# Should oauth 2.0 client credential return same token after resetting the client secret?

Tags: security, oauth, oauth-2.0

*I have knowledge of oauth, But i have a small doubt like should oauth return different token after resetting the client secret if current token is not expired.   *

Comment: please add significant code associated with your question. it makes your question more candidate for answer.